# Team Foundation Server (TFS) Best Option for complete rebrand of project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have TFS project with multiple .net solutions/ applications within it.

MY TFS looks like:
TFS Project 1

- .net solution 1
- .net solution 2
- .net solution 3

I have to completely re brand one solution/ application including changing all js files/ css/ images etc. What is the best way to handle this in TFS:

1. create a new branch and leave existing project in branch called Pre-rebrand
2. label
3. create a brand new solution... ?

1 issue though is while the rebrand is going on lets say it takes 1 month. If any errors are found in the current application these would need to be fixed and possible merged/ or also done in the new rebranded application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a great reason to use a branch to me.

Comment: Thanks. That was my initial thiught. Would u suggest creating a branch from master labeling it like prerebrand and leave it their unless changes are needed. If i get bug fixes can I merge just them back into master without anything else. Ie a single function etc. Thanks

Comment: I would branch off for the rebranding work (leave master as "pre-rebrand"), and only merge to master once you are done.